# Finding Input and output tensors from .pb file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite

I created a .pb model thanks to roboflow.ai and I'm now trying to convert the .pb file into .tflite so I can use it in an Android app I'm hoping to develop. I'm struggling to do the conversion because I have to put in my 'input' and 'output' tensors.

I found a script that gave me my input tensor as 'image_tensor' but it gives me my output tensors as:

`'Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/Switch',
'raw_detection_boxes',
'MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert',
'detection_boxes',
'detection_scores',
'Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/SortByField/TopKV2',
'detection_multiclass_scores',
'Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/SortByField/Assert/Assert',
'Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/Switch_1',
'Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/SortByField_1/Assert/Assert',
'detection_classes',
'num_detections',
'Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/SortByField_1/TopKV2',
'Preprocessor/map/while/Switch_1',
'Preprocessor/map/while/Switch',
'raw_detection_scores'`

I've tried all of this and different combinations of this but I'm unsure what I should be using (or if it even is the correct thing).

I'm trying to put this into the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

localpb = 'retrained_graph_eyes1za.pb'
tflite_file = 'retrained_graph_eyes1za.lite'

print("{} -> {}".format(localpb, tflite_file))

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
    localpb, 
    ['input'], 
    ['final_result']
)

tflite_model = converter.convert()

open(tflite_file,'wb').write(tflite_model)

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

I'm using TensorFlow v1x as this is what roboflow.ai recommends.

Any help?

Comment: Transforming .pb to .tflite is a pain sometimes. Specially at versions Tensorflow v.1 ... You have to check operators compatibility [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility)  before you try it. I would recommend train the model again with tensorflow version 2. It is easier the transformation

Comment: Thanks for this, I found my input and output tensors eventually but then encountered another error. In the end I switched to a different tutorial and was able to train my .tflite model which works with teh Tesorflow Android Studio example.. I'm still using Tensorflow 1x. I'd love to find a good end to end example on Tensorflow 2, preferably using Yolo V5. As an Android developer, I've spent ages on this when all I want is my model on a mobile phone.